# How to make my website google search result as shown on picture? Subdirectories

Tags: seo, google-search

When I search for yahoo, godaddy etc on google then they display sub-directories like shown on attached picture. But my website doesn't show that kind of stuff when it's found on google.
What was the problem?[image]

Comment: I'm voting for closing this question as off-topic. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on the network site Pro Webmasters at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for Google Sitelink on the organic SERP part is entirely automated.

Your content must be useful to the user and your web site structure must allow the algorithm to find Google Sitelink.

> “First, ensure that long, multi-topic pages on your site are
>   well-structured and broken into distinct logical sections. Second,
>   ensure that each section has an associated anchor with a descriptive
>   name (i.e., not just “Section 2.1″), and that your page includes a
>   “table of contents” which links to the individual anchors. The new
>   in-snippet links only appear for relevant queries, so you won’t see it
>   on the results all the time — only when we think that a link to a
>   section would be highly useful for a particular query.”
>   [Source](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.cz/2009/09/using-named-anchors-to-identify.html)

It also appears that user behaviour and quality/number of internal and external links count when considering Google Sitelink.

There is a patent related to Google algorithm, (I believe partly related to your Sitelink question), [here the link](http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PG01&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=%2220060287985%22.PGNR.&OS=DN/20060287985&RS=DN/20060287985).